# Java ExecutorService get feedback for all tasks

Tags: java, executorservice

I want to send email to multiple(500,1000,2000) users.

I have done that using `ExecutorService`.

But now I want to collect the number of successful emails sent and the number of failed emails out of total records.

I have implemented this like:

```
int startValue=0;
int endValue=0;
List userEmailList = getListFromDB();
ExecutorService  e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
Collection c = new ArrayList();

while (someflag) 
{  
// in MyTask class I am sending email to users.
c.add(new MyTask(startValue, endValue,userEmailList));  
}    
e.invokeAll(c);   //Here I am calling invokeall .
pool.shutdown();


public class MyTask implements Callable<String> { 
  MyTask(startValue, endValue,userEmailList){
  }

  public String call(){
//e.g.   batch 1 will have  - startValue => endValue   = 0 -100
//e.g.   batch 2 will have  - startValue => endValue   = 101 -199
//e.g.   batch 3 will have  - startValue => endValue   = 200 -299
//e.g.   batch 4 will have  - startValue => endValue   = 300 -399
//e.g.   batch 5 will have  - startValue => endValue   = 400 - 499

for(int i=startValue;i<endValue;i++){
      sendEmailToUser(userEmailList.get(i)){
}
 }
```

}

But future.get() returning  me number of task completed. so from above code it will return me 5 task.

But I wanted  output as no of failed  emails and number of successful email sent.

for e.g if there are 500 email users and if 20 falied , then output should be 480 success and 20 failed.

But with above code I am getting only no of task . ie 5 task

Can anybody tell me how I can get  feedback from all concurrent tasks (*Not* the number of tasks completed).

Comment: Can you please post the complete snippet. I think you need return type as `List<String>` rather than just `String`

Answer (score 1):

Your `MyTask` returns a `String` (implements `Callable<String>`), which doesn't make much sense in your case. You are free to return any other type you want. Unfortunately you'll need some simple POJO to contain the results, e.g.:

```
public class Result {

    private final int successCount;
    private final int failureCount;

    public Result(int successCount, int failureCount) {
        this.successCount = successCount;
        this.failureCount = failureCount;
    }

}
```

And return it after given batch is done (implement `Callable<Result>`). Of course your `MyTask` will then have to keep track of how many e-mails failed and return correct values wrapped around `Result`.

However I see several ways your code can be improved. First of all instead of passing `startValue, endValue` range to `MyTask` just use `userEmailList.subList(startValue, endValue)` - which will simplify your code *a lot*:

```
new MyTask(userEmailList.subList(startValue, endValue));
//...

public class MyTask implements Callable<Result> { 
    MyTask(userEmailList){
    }

    public Result call(){
        for(email: userEmailList) {
            sendEmailToUser(email);
            //collect results here
        }
        return new Result(...);
    }
 }
```

On the other hand there is nothing wrong in creating `MyTask` to send just one e-mail. That instead of aggregating counts in given batch you simply check the result of one task (one e-mail) - either nothing or exception (or single `Boolean`). It's much easier and shouldn't be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I could see that your call method is declared to return a String but your code doesn't return anything (probably incomplete snippet). And from your statement, I understand that you are returning whether the task is completed or not and not whether the mail has been sent. You could make the `sendEmailToUser` return the success of failure depending on whether the mail has been sent successfully and get the result using `Future.get`